# How to get the SRC previous and next images for use in image.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

Trying to remove the image from the function [previous_image_link ()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_image_link) directly through the arguments of this function I do this is not possible. Therefore, try to simply extract the SRC:

```html
<td style="background: url(

<?php

    $html = previous_image_link('full');
    preg_match_all('/<img [^>]*src=["|\']([^"|\']+)/i', $html, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[1] as $key=>$value) {
        echo $value;
    }
?>

) no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
```

However, instead of the expected

```html
<td style="background: url(/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/tiaurus.info_20150323125918.jpg") no-repeat center center; background-size: cover;">
```

getting

```html
<td height="3166" class="attachment-full" alt="img_alt_text" src="/wp-content/blablabla/20150323125918.jpg" 8176"="">) no-repeat center center;background-size: cover;"&gt;
            </td>
) no-repeat center center;background-size: cover;">
```

As in my case it is necessary to use preg_match_all?

Or can someone tell me how to get the SRC previous and next images for use in image.php?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP function `pre_match` and eliminate the `foreach` loop.

```
preg_match('/ src=["\']([^\s]+)["\']/', $html, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Since your `$html` string only has one `src` value to retrieve, `preg_match` is sufficient. `preg_match_all` is designed for multiple matches.

Also, since `src=` is unique in the string, we can narrow down our pattern to something that starts with `src=`, and is wrapped by either double quotes or single quotes. `["\']` is a character class that limits the match to one character that is either a double quote or a single quote. (The single quote is escaped because I'm using single quotes to delimit the regular expression string.)

The parenthesis `()` capture a value and add it to the `$matches` array.

`[^]` is a negative character class, in other words, don't match any of the characters listed here. `+` matches one or more of the previous character. So `[^\s]+` is simply saying, match one or more characters that are not a space character.

Given:

```
$html = '<a href="/33279/retro-kartinyi-iz-skotcha-max-zorn"><img width="1600" height="900" class="attachment-full" style="width: 516px; height: 290px;" alt="Max Zorn" src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/tiaurus.info_20150323125854.jpg"></a>';
```

`echo $matches[1];` returns:

```
/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/tiaurus.info_20150323125854.jpg
```

Comment: Don't work. Result: `<td height="3166" class="attachment-full" alt="img_alt_text" src="/wp-content/blablabla/20150323125918.jpg" 8176"="">) no-repeat center center;background-size: cover;"&gt;
            </td>
) no-repeat center center;background-size: cover;">`

Comment: Can you provide an example of `$html`?

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it would make your answer even more helpful.

Comment: Example of $html: `<a href="/33279/retro-kartinyi-iz-skotcha-max-zorn"><img width="1600" height="900" class="attachment-full" style="width: 516px; height: 290px;" alt="Max Zorn" src="/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/tiaurus.info_20150323125854.jpg"></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to use a regex to extract the URL, I think you should try to reverse engineer the `previous_image_link` function to find a more direct approach.

`previous_image_link` is essentially a wrapper around [`adjacent_image_link`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/adjacent_image_link/). Once you see how the adjacent image is being fetched, it is pretty easy to write a function that fetches the image src instead of the formatted link:

```
function adjacent_image_src($prev = true) {
    $post = get_post();
    $attachments = array_values( get_children( array( 'post_parent' => $post->post_parent, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID' ) ) );

    foreach ( $attachments as $k => $attachment ) {
        if ( $attachment->ID == $post->ID ) {
            break;
        }
    }

    $attachment_id = false;
    $src = false;

    if ( $attachments ) {
        $k = $prev ? $k - 1 : $k + 1;

        if ( isset( $attachments[ $k ] ) ) {
            $attachment_id = $attachments[ $k ]->ID;
            $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id );
        }
    }

    return $src;
}
```

You could also just return `$attachment_id` and then you could get whatever information you need about the attachment.

Comment: Return Attay. To get SRC, should be `return $src[0];` **Many thanks for function code!**